# How to add 'Optional Claims' dynamically for AzureAD registered application?

Tags: c#, azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I want to add optional Claims under ID token for my application which is registered under Azure AD.
Is there any commandlet available which can be used for this purpose?

I need to collect these Optional Claims first and then I want to set them at app level. ( i.e. Want to automate the process of manually collecting optional claim and including them for Azure Ad application ).  Following ID claims needed.

[image]

and they should be added under the following area.

[image]

Is there any commandlet available for collecting and then later on setting those optional claims at App level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update optional claims using [`az ad`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad?view=azure-cli-latest) command-line tool. Specifically you can update optional claims using a `manifest.json` file resembling the following:

```
{
    "idToken": [
        {
            "name": "auth_time",
            "source": null,
            "essential": false
        }
    ],
    "accessToken": [
        {
            "name": "email",
            "source": null,
            "essential": false
        }
    ]
}
```

and then performing the following command:

`az ad app update --id <CLIENT_ID> --optional-claims @manifest.json`

[Documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/app?view=azure-cli-latest#az_ad_app_update)

EDIT: If you want to use Azure PowerShell, you should use the `AzureAD` module and commandlet `Set-AzureADApplication`. This cmdlet contains a parameter `-OptionalClaims`. [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/set-azureadapplication?view=azureadps-2.0).

Comment: Yes, I want to use 'Set-AzureADApplication' commandlet for this.

Comment: But there would be a question : How to collect these claims dynamically? I don't want to hardcode these claims by certain means. What if they get change tomorrow from Microsoft side. Is there any commandlet available for collecting these optional claims?

Comment: I understand the question now. I don't think there is any API for retrieving names of claims, but I also think this is not a valid concern. Changing the names of these claims is a major breaking change. If they were to change this they would need to introduce a new token version (v3) and maintain backwards compatibility with v2 (current).

Comment: @TiamoIdzenga Why am getting this error while trying the cli command ?

ERROR: Please run 'az login' to setup account.

Failed Azure CLI Command: az ad app update --id xxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx-1xxxxxxx  --optional-claims 'C:\Users\VssAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\manifest.json'. Any clue on this?