# Adding optional claims is not reflecting on Azure AD

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-cli

I am trying to add optional claims for an app registered on Azure AD. I was following [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/update-azadapplication?view=azps-8.3.0) but the changes are not reflecting on the app's manifest. Still it is showing null or empty array like the below image.

[image: Image from Manifest]

I tried to follow this  [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68742188/how-to-add-optional-claims-dynamically-for-azuread-registered-application) also but no luck.

```
$idTokenClaim = @()

            $idTokenClaim += @([PSCustomObject] @{
                    name = "upn"
                    source = $null
                    essential = "true"
                    additionalProperties = @()
                })

            $optionalClaims = @{
                idToken     = $idTokenClaim
                accessToken = @()
                saml2Token  = @()
            } | ConvertTo-Json -Compress | ConvertTo-Json


          az ad app update --id $($application.appId)--optional-claims '$optionalClaims'"
```

The JSON output for the $optionalClaims is :

[image]

Did I miss anything? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can directly try to update the Manifest by the required Optional Claims by following this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims#configuring-optional-claims) and Save.

Comment: @Rukmini No I have to do this using a powershell command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/update-azadapplication?view=azps-8.3.0), in order to update `OptionalClaim` property, we need to use hash table information.

Below are the steps which needs to be followed:

1. Create a test.json on your machine with similar content like below (you can copy it from the manifest file the below section)

```html
{
        "idToken": [
            {
                "additionalProperties": [],
                "essential": false,
                "name": "ctry",
                "source": null
            },
            {
                "additionalProperties": [],
                "essential": false,
                "name": "acct",
                "source": null
            },
            {
                "additionalProperties": [],
                "essential": false,
                "name": "given_name",
                "source": null
            }
        ],
        "accessToken": [],
        "saml2Token": [
            {
                "additionalProperties": [],
                "essential": false,
                "name": "upn",
                "source": null
            }
        ]
    }
```

2. Since we need to pass Hashtable to -optional claim property we need to convert the above JSON to Hash Table.

- In PowerShell 7 we can covert the above JSON Hash table by using below cmdlet

```html
Get-Content <pathofAboveJsonFile> | ConvertFrom-Json -AsHashtable
```

[image]

3. Use the cmdlet `update-AzADApplication`to update the optionalClaim for an application in AzureAD.

```html
  Update-AzADApplication -objectid <objectidoftheapplication> -optionalclaim $hastable
```

Comment: I was trying to accomplish this using azure cli  method. As you mentioned I created one Json file and tried to call from it. Now am getting some error like ERROR: Please run 'az login' to setup account.. Not sure why it is happening

Comment: upvoted for giving me some insight about the issue. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

As Givary mentioned you need to hash the table information. Your Json file seems to be okay so there should be some other issues with your code.

```
            $idTokenClaim = @()

            $idTokenClaim += @([PSCustomObject] @{
                    name = "upn"
                    source = $null
                    essential = "true"
                    additionalProperties = @()
                })

            $optionalClaims = @{
                idToken     = $idTokenClaim
                accessToken = @()
                saml2Token  = @()
            } | ConvertTo-Json -Compress | ConvertTo-Json

               $optionalClaimFile ="<filepath>\<filename>"
              $optionalClaims | Out-File $optionalClaimFile -Encoding ASCII
          
 az ad app update --id $($application.appId)--optional-claims '$optionalClaimFile '"
```

This will work I believe.